# Counting non RST packets?

Tags: ip

It is possible to count connections who do not respond with RST flag set in connection initiated ? I am interested to log IP, MAC and TTL.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using standard tools such as `tcpdump`.

See [this reply](https://superuser.com/a/356924/52492) to another question. It provides an example of processing tcpdump output in real time using a scripting language. I believe that could be extended to do what you want. Substitute your favourite scripting language.

Comment: I want to **pairing** in real time one-to-one syn packets (who began a connection) with ACK packets.
In this way I want to know IP, MAC and TTL for syn-flood connections.
Also, I want to pairing packets with ACK set incorrectly with  RST packets.
And I have no idea how to ...